# Qt 5.4 cannot set app icon on OSX

Tags: macos, qt, icons

I'm having issues with setting an app icon when using Qt 5.4. I followed what this page says: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/appicon.html#setting-the-application-icon-on-os-x
but nothing works. When browsing .app's contents, there's not even a .plist file! Am I doing something wrong?

Edit: adding .pro file

```
QT       += core gui multimedia
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
TARGET = Congolexicomatiseur
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
    dialog.cpp \
    clickablehollowlabel.cpp \
    about.cpp \
    clickablelabel.cpp

HEADERS  += dialog.h \
    clickablehollowlabel.h \
    about.h \
    clickablelabel.h

FORMS    += dialog.ui \
    about.ui

RESOURCES += \
    resources.qrc

ICON = img/icon.icns
RC_ICONS = img/icon.ico
```

Comment: Can you add your `.pro` file where you are setting the icon?

Comment: Looks great so far and on my system, this `.pro` file works. Could you add the output of `grep -C 4 icns "your-build-directory/Makefile"` to the question? Please link my name in the comment when you did that, such that I get notified.

Comment: @SimonWarta : my makefile doesn't contain anything that may come from the "ICON =" directive. Not a single line.

Comment: @SimonWarta : found this in compile output: WARNING: Could not resolve Info.plist: '../../../../Qt5.4.1/5.4/clang_64/mkspecs/macx-clang/Info.plist.app'. Check if QMAKE_INFO_PLIST points to a valid file.

Comment: Wow, that is valuable. Looks like a broken Qt installation. Did you move your Qt Installation after installing? (You must not do that) Try to reinstall Qt.

Comment: @SimonWarta : already did that, it's the very first thing I did. I'm going to try to find traces of Qt in LIbrary folders, who knows...

Comment: Arg, where does the `.app` come from in '../../../../Qt5.4.1/5.4/clang_64/mkspecs/macx-clang/Info.plist.app'? Can you add the output of `grep -C 4 "Info.plist" your-build-directory/Makefile` to your question?

Comment: @SimonWarta : again, nothing :'( The relative path points to my Qt installation folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74137/discussion-between-simon-warta-and-deadbird).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Randomly found out that Qt, even when uninstalled, keeps setting files hidden somewhere: [Where does QtCreator save its settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742663/where-does-qtcreator-save-its-settings)

To solve the problem:

- uninstall Qt
- delete these files
- reinstall Qt.